# LACP NIC Bonding always uses only one interface port event at Hash policy layer 2+3

Tags: networking, netplan, interface, network-bonding

We are facing an issue with UBUNTU 20.04 NIC bonding LACP 802.3ad. Two 100G NIC ports are bonded via netplan and the settings are - MTU 9216, Hash policy 2+3, LACP fast, and the same is configured from the 100G switch.

We used `iperf` with multi-processor threads up to 24 but the `nload` test shows only one NIC interface is saturated i.e. 92Gbps and never goes above it. Please share your thoughts. (A few screenshots are attached)

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v5.15.0-91-generic

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2+3 (2)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP active: on
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable

Slave Interface: ens1f1np1
MII Status: up
Speed: 100000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 4
Permanent HW addr: 04:3f:72:c3:cb:81
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0

Slave Interface: ens1f0np0
MII Status: up
Speed: 100000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 2
Permanent HW addr: 04:3f:72:c3:cb:80
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0'''

netplan:
'''network:
  ethernets:
    ens2f0np0:
      mtu: 9216
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
    ens1f0np0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      mtu: 9216
    ens1f1np1:
      mtu: 9216
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bonds:
    bond2:
      mtu: 9216
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2+3
        lacp-rate: fast
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

[image: nload result]

Comment: not clear that it's related to the problem you're having, but the netplan config posted seems to be incomplete, because you should a bond defined but you haven't added any interfaces to it.

Comment: Hi #slangasek, we have added the interfaces to the bond along with static IP configurations which are not shared in this post.

interfaces:
        - ens1f0np0
        - ens1f1np1

Comment: Actually, just got it working with the hash policy assigned to 3+4 instead of 2+3 algorithm. Thanks for your time mate.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question,
Please add the hash algorithm the same between the switch bond interface and the server bond interface. Example if the switch is configured to 3+4 transmit hash policy then keep it same in the server operating system.

Command to set the hash policy:

```
echo layer3+4 > /sys/class/net/bond3/bonding/xmit_hash_policy
```

Thanks,
Aagi